# React: Passing props between classes is always undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass a simple list from a parent class to a child but "props" is always *undefined*. I've made my research here and tried several ways but the result is always the same: "undefined". 
How can I get the cards list assigned to the corresponding field in child class state? (Evidently, there are my first React steps)

**Game class (parent)**

```
import React from "react";
import Hand from "./Hand/Hand";

let hand1 = [{ id: 1, value: 5 }, { id: 2, value: 4 }, { id: 3, value: 1 }];

export default class Game extends React.Component {
  static initialState = () => ({
    deckId: getDeckId
  });
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <Hand cards={this.hand1} />
        </div>
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Hand class (child)**

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "./../Card/Card";

const flipUp = card => {
  this.setState(
    prevState => ({
      flippedCards: prevState.flippedCards.concat(card)
    }),
    this.sumCards()
  );
};

const flipDown = card => {
  this.setState(
    prevState => ({
      flippedCards: prevState.flippedCards.filter(c => c.id !== card.id)
    }),
    this.sumCards()
  );
};

const CardList = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.cards.map(card => (
        <Card key={card.id} flipUp={this.flipUp} flipDown={this.flipDown} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default class Hand extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    console.log(props); //this is always undefined
    this.state = {
      cards: props.cards,
      flippedCards: [],
      currentSum: 0
    };
  }

  sumCards = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      currentSum: prevState.flippedCards.reduce(
        (acc, card) => card.value + acc,
        0
      )
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>
          <CardList cards={this.state.cards} />
        </div>
        <div style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>{this.state.currentSum}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hand1` is a variable that is not assigned to the `this` context in the scope of the parent class, `Game`. You can use its values directly as the prop value:

```
import React from 'react';
import Hand from './Hand/Hand';

let hand1 = [
  {id: 1, value:5},
  {id: 2, value:4},
  {id: 3, value:1}
]

export default class Game extends React.Component {
  static initialState = () => ({
    deckId: getDeckId
  });
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
            <Hand cards={hand1}/>
        </div>    
      <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

To be able to pass the values they way you tried first you should define it in the class constructor.

```
export default class Game extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.hand1 = [
      {id: 1, value:5},
      {id: 2, value:4},
      {id: 3, value:1}
    ];
  }

  static initialState = () => ({
    deckId: getDeckId
  });

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
            <Hand cards={this.hand1}/>
        </div>    
      <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow! That was easy. Thanks @Dez, I'll accept your answer as soon as I can